# Why are my CSS classes having no effect

Tags: html, css

Why cant i get background to change when i reference via a css style sheet, but works okay when done directly with color on inline style (i.e only columns 1 and 4 change their background color)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td  bgcolor="#D6D6C2">Column 1</td>
    <td  class="releasetableheading">Column 2</td>
    <td  class=".releasetableheading">Column 3</td>
    <td  style="background-color:#D6D6C2">Column 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.releasetableheading {
    background-color=#D6D6C2;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ijabz/vnkqhz5h/ for full example

Comment: ..because the syntax is wrong. It should be `background-color: #D6D6C2` (no equal sign). Also, you don't need to add periods, `.`, to the class attributes.

Comment: Doh, thought it would be something stupid but just couldn't see it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is off.  Use colon instead of equals sign, and remove period from class declaration.

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vnkqhz5h/1/

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td  bgcolor="#D6D6C2">Column 1</td>
    <td  class="releasetableheading">Column 2</td>
    <td  class="releasetableheading">Column 3</td>
    <td  style="background-color:#D6D6C2">Column 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.releasetableheading {
    background-color: #D6D6C2;
}
```

Note that `bgcolor` is deprecated and should not be used and you should use classes, not inline styles whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use bgcolor attribute, it's not supported in HTML5.  In HTML, you simply define your class that way :

```
 <td class="myClass"></td>
```

And you can define a unique ID for an HTML element that way

```
 <td id="myId"></td>
```

Then, in your CSS, the syntax has to be written that way:

```
 .myClass{
     background-color: #000;
  }
 #myId{
    background-color: #fff;
 }
```

Suffix for class is a dot (.) and for id is a hashtag (#).

You always write your property that way in CSS.  "property: value".

Hope it helped !